# What NLP library is suitable for basic analysis of the English texts on the shared hosting?

Tags: php, python, nlp, shared-hosting

I need to make a syntax analysis of some simple English sentences on inexpensive shared hostings with PHP and MySQL support. In fact, I will have no special admin rights for installing and using additional things like JVM (or modifying httpd.conf). Unfortunately (in my situation), most of NLP tools are written in Java. Can I use Python libraries? Do many of shared hostings support Python 2.7 and higher? Are there any pure PHP syntax parsers for the English language? I don't want to make the user of my syntax parser to install additional tools. It must work out of the box or require little magic without special admin rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most comprehensive Natrual Language TookKit out there in the Python Community happens to be exactly that!

- [NLTK](http://nltk.org/)

**To Install:**

```
pip install nltk
```

or:

```
easy_install nltk
```

or:

1. Download: https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/nltk/nltk-2.0.4.tar.gz
2. Extract: nltk-2.0.4.tar.gz `tar zxvf nltk-2.0.4.tar.gz`
3. Setup: `cd nltk-2.0.4 && python setup.py install --home=$HOME`